# Image overlay in ffmpeg-python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I am trying to add a watermark to a video using `ffmpeg-python`. My pipeline is very straightforward, but I've been unable to figure out the syntax:

```
new_input = ffmpeg.input(file_name).filter('overlay', 'overlay.png').output(fout).run()
```

This throws the error `Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_overlay_7` , likely because the syntax for the overlay filter is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since overlay filter requires two inputs, the syntax is a bit confusing.

There are good example [here](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).

---

Here is a code sample:

```
import ffmpeg

file_name = 'input.mp4'
fout = 'output.mp4'

(
    ffmpeg
    .filter([ffmpeg.input(file_name), ffmpeg.input('overlay.png')], 'overlay', 10, 10)
    .output(fout)
    .run()
)
```